# How to disable External Logins in Identity Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am in the process of integrating a simplefied authentication process into a asp.net core 2.1 application, where users are logging in via the UI by default, but there is also the possibility to aquire a token and call some secured api endpoints to retrieve some data needed for reporting.

The issue I am facing is, that with the default configuration everything works, but adding the token config throws some weird errors.

If I do not add `AddCookie("Identity.External")`, call to the onGet method at `/Identity/Account/Login` throws the exception

> InvalidOperationException: No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.External'. The registered sign-out schemes are: Identity.Application. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Identity.External",...)?

If I do not specify `options.DefaultScheme = "Identity.Application";` the user is not successfully signed in.

If I do not add `.AddCookie("Identity.External")` and `.AddCookie("Identity.TwoFactorUserId")` the logout process throws the same exception as above.

For the login process, this is simply rectified by removing the line `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);`. If I do not use external schemes I do not need to sign out of them, right?

This brings me to my problem: How can I disable external logins and multi factor authentication in Identity Core, so I do not have to add those cookies in the first place? Furthermore, why do I have to specifiy a cookie named "Identity.Application", which is not the case in the default configuration? I'm pretty sure this is just another issue of me not thoroughly understanding the problem at hand, so I am grateful for any clarification on this.

This is my Identity config from the Startup.cs I have also scaffolded out the complete Identity UI with a custom IdentityUser class.

```
var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
    options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
    options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
});

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    /*...*/     
};

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Identity.Application";
})
//.AddCookie("Identity.External")
//.AddCookie("Identity.TwoFactorUserId")
.AddCookie("Identity.Application", opt =>
{
    opt.SlidingExpiration = true;
})

.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    options.SaveToken = true;
});

var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
{
    //removed
});
builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```